# Hbase setup configuration: HMaster is not running

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to setup HBase in a fully distributed mode: consisting of 1 master and 2 region servers. I have set HBASE_MANAGES_ZK = true in hbase-env.sh. The hadoop cluster is running on the cluster with following configurations:

Master: node-master 
Regionserver1: node1
Regionserver2: node2

When I am starting HBase, I can see that RegionServers are getting started and HQuorumPeer on master also, but HMaster is not showing.

Please find the logs as below:
Master hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
        <property>
            <name>hbase.master</name>
            <value>nodemaster.hbasecluster.com:60000</value>
            <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.A value of ‘local’ runs the master and a regionserver in a single </description>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
             <value>hdfs://nodemaster.hbasecluster.com:9000/hbase</value>
             <description>The directory shared by region servers.</description>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
             <value>true</value>
             <description>The mode the cluster will be in. Possible values are false: standalone and pseudo-distributed setups with managed Zookeeper true: fully-distributed with unmanaged Zookeeper Quorum (see hbase-env.sh) </description>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.zookeeper.distributed</name>
             <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
             <value>/usr/local/zookeeper</value>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
             <value>2181</value>
             <description>Property from ZooKeeper’s config zoo.cfg. The port at which the clients will connect. </description>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
             <value>nodemaster.hbasecluster.com</value>
             <description>Comma separated list of servers in the ZooKeeper Quorum. </description>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.tmp.dir</name>
             <value>/hbase/tmp</value>
             <description>Temporary directory on the local filesystem.</description>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hosts on master

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.2.154 nodemaster.hbasecluster.com node-master
192.168.2.186 node1.hbasecluster.com node1
192.168.2.187 node2.hbasecluster.com node2
```

Logs on regionserver1

```
Fri Aug 17 12:32:15 IST 2018 Starting regionserver on node1.hbasecluster.com
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15701
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 10000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15701
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
2018-08-17 12:32:15,420 INFO  [main] regionserver.HRegionServer: STARTING executorService HRegionServer
2018-08-17 12:32:15,422 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: HBase 2.1.0
2018-08-17 12:32:15,422 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Source code repository git://zhangduo-Gen8/home/zhangduo/hbase/code revision=e1673bb0bbfea21d6e5dba73e013b09b8b49b89b
2018-08-17 12:32:15,422 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: Compiled by zhangduo on Tue Jul 10 17:26:48 CST 2018
2018-08-17 12:32:15,422 INFO  [main] util.VersionInfo: From source with checksum c8fb98abf2988c0490954e15806337d7
2018-08-17 12:32:15,703 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: hbase.tmp.dir: /tmp/hbase-root
2018-08-17 12:32:15,703 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: hbase.rootdir: hdfs://nodemaster.hbasecluster.com:9000/hbase
2018-08-17 12:32:15,703 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: hbase.cluster.distributed: true
2018-08-17 12:32:15,703 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: hbase.zookeeper.quorum: nodemaster.hbasecluster.com
2018-08-17 12:32:15,703 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_LOGFILE=hbase-root-regionserver-node1.hbasecluster.com.log
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:LANG=en_US.UTF-8
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:XDG_SESSION_ID=182
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:MAIL=/var/mail/root
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:LOGNAME=root
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_REST_OPTS=
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:PWD=/root
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_ROOT_LOGGER=INFO,RFA
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:SHELL=/bin/bash
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_ENV_INIT=true
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_IDENT_STRING=root
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_ZNODE_FILE=/tmp/hbase-root-regionserver.znode
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:SSH_CLIENT=192.168.2.154 46760 22
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_LOG_PREFIX=hbase-root-regionserver-node1.hbasecluster.com
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_LOG_DIR=/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../logs
2018-08-17 12:32:15,704 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:USER=root
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/spymemcached-2.12.2.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/xz-1.0.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/zookeeper-3.4.10.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/audience-annotations-0.5.0.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/findbugs-annotations-1.3.9-1.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/htrace-core4-4.2.0-incubating.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar:/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:SSH_CONNECTION=192.168.2.154 46760 192.168.2.186 22
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_AUTOSTART_FILE=/tmp/hbase-root-regionserver.autostart
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_NICENESS=0
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_OPTS= -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC   -Dhbase.log.dir=/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../logs -Dhbase.log.file=hbase-root-regionserver-node1.hbasecluster.com.log -Dhbase.home.dir=/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/.. -Dhbase.id.str=root -Dhbase.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Dhbase.security.logger=INFO,RFAS
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_SECURITY_LOGGER=INFO,RFAS
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_THRIFT_OPTS=
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HBASE_HOME=/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/..
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:SHLVL=3
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:HOME=/root
2018-08-17 12:32:15,705 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: env:MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=4
2018-08-17 12:32:15,706 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: vmName=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, vmVendor=Oracle Corporation, vmVersion=25.171-b11
2018-08-17 12:32:15,707 INFO  [main] util.ServerCommandLine: vmInputArguments=[-Dproc_regionserver, -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -Dhbase.log.dir=/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/../logs, -Dhbase.log.file=hbase-root-regionserver-node1.hbasecluster.com.log, -Dhbase.home.dir=/root/install/hbase-2.1.0/bin/.., -Dhbase.id.str=root, -Dhbase.root.logger=INFO,RFA, -Dhbase.security.logger=INFO,RFAS]
2018-08-17 12:32:21,194 INFO  [main] metrics.MetricRegistries: Loaded MetricRegistries class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.metrics.impl.MetricRegistriesImpl
2018-08-17 12:32:21,245 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-08-17 12:32:21,489 INFO  [main] regionserver.RSRpcServices: regionserver/node1:16020 server-side Connection retries=45
2018-08-17 12:32:21,503 INFO  [main] ipc.RpcExecutor: Instantiated default.FPBQ.Fifo with queueClass=class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue; numCallQueues=3, maxQueueLength=300, handlerCount=30
2018-08-17 12:32:21,505 INFO  [main] ipc.RpcExecutor: Instantiated priority.FPBQ.Fifo with queueClass=class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue; numCallQueues=2, maxQueueLength=300, handlerCount=20
2018-08-17 12:32:21,505 INFO  [main] ipc.RpcExecutor: Instantiated replication.FPBQ.Fifo with queueClass=class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue; numCallQueues=1, maxQueueLength=300, handlerCount=3
2018-08-17 12:32:21,639 INFO  [main] ipc.RpcServerFactory: Creating org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcServer hosting hbase.pb.ClientService, hbase.pb.AdminService
2018-08-17 12:32:21,832 INFO  [main] io.ByteBufferPool: Created with bufferSize=64 KB and maxPoolSize=1.88 KB
2018-08-17 12:32:21,937 ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServer: Failed construction RegionServer
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Constructor threw an exception for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcServer
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateWithCustomCtor(ReflectionUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServerFactory.createRpcServer(RpcServerFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.createRpcServer(RSRpcServices.java:1271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:1238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:1191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.createRpcServices(HRegionServer.java:733)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:571)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.constructRegionServer(HRegionServer.java:2991)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.start(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.run(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.main(HRegionServer.java:3009)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:58)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: bind(..) failed: Address already in use
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newIOException(Errors.java:117)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.bind(Socket.java:285)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doBind(AbstractEpollChannel.java:714)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollServerSocketChannel.doBind(EpollServerSocketChannel.java:70)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:558)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1283)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:989)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:254)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:364)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:309)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-08-17 12:32:21,940 ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine: Region server exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed construction of Regionserver: class org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.constructRegionServer(HRegionServer.java:2994)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.start(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServerCommandLine.run(HRegionServerCommandLine.java:87)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.main(HRegionServer.java:3009)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.constructRegionServer(HRegionServer.java:2991)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Constructor threw an exception for org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.NettyRpcServer
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiateWithCustomCtor(ReflectionUtils.java:45)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServerFactory.createRpcServer(RpcServerFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.createRpcServer(RSRpcServices.java:1271)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:1238)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.<init>(RSRpcServices.java:1191)
```

I 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.createRpcServices(HRegionServer.java:733)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.(HRegionServer.java:571)
        ... 10 more
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ReflectionUtils.instantiate(ReflectionUtils.java:58)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: bind(..) failed: Address already in use
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newIOException(Errors.java:117)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.bind(Socket.java:285)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doBind(AbstractEpollChannel.java:714)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollServerSocketChannel.doBind(EpollServerSocketChannel.java:70)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:558)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1283)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:989)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:254)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:364)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:309)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
        at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

regionserver hbase-site.xml

```
<configuration>
        <property>
            <name>hbase.master</name>
            <value>nodemaster.hbasecluster.com:60000</value>
            <description>The host and port that the HBase master runs at.A value of ‘local’ runs the master and a regionserver in a single </description>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
             <value>hdfs://nodemaster.hbasecluster.com:9000/hbase</value>
             <description>The directory shared by region servers.</description>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
             <value>true</value>
             <description>The mode the cluster will be in. Possible values are false: standalone and pseudo-distributed setups with managed Zookeeper true: fully-distributed with unmanaged Zookeeper Quorum (see hbase-env.sh) </description>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
             <value>2181</value>
             <description>Property from ZooKeeper’s config zoo.cfg. The port at which the clients will connect. </description>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
             <value>nodemaster.hbasecluster.com</value>
             <description>Property from ZooKeeper’s config zoo.cfg. The port at which the clients will connect. </description>
        </property>
        <property>
             <name>hbase.zookeeper.distributed</name>
             <value>true</value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hosts file in regionserver1

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
192.168.2.154 nodemaster.hbasecluster.com node-master
192.168.2.186 node1.hbasecluster.com node1
192.168.2.187 node2.hbasecluster.com node2
```

Master node jps output:

```
19717 SecondaryNameNode
20441 HQuorumPeer
20781 Jps
19470 NameNode
19887 ResourceManager
```

regionserver jps output:

```
28404 NodeManager
28185 DataNode
28844 Jps
28687 HRegionServer
```

EDIT: I was trying to run ./bin/start-hbase.sh. When I used the commands ./bin/hbase-daemon.sh start master I get the following error in my master logs.

```
2018-08-20 11:50:42,742 ERROR [main] regionserver.HRegionServer: Failed construction RegionServer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/htrace/SamplerBuilder
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:635)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2669)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CommonFSUtils.getRootDir(CommonFSUtils.java:358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CommonFSUtils.isValidWALRootDir(CommonFSUtils.java:407)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.CommonFSUtils.getWALRootDir(CommonFSUtils.java:383)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.initializeFileSystem(HRegionServer.java:691)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.<init>(HRegionServer.java:600)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.<init>(HMaster.java:484)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.constructMaster(HMaster.java:2965)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.startMaster(HMasterCommandLine.java:236)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMasterCommandLine.run(HMasterCommandLine.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.ServerCommandLine.doMain(ServerCommandLine.java:149)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.main(HMaster.java:2983)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.SamplerBuilder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 25 more
2018-08-20 11:50:42,744 ERROR [main] master.HMasterCommandLine: Master exiting
```

The zookeeper was able to create connections to the slaves and the Region servers are running on each slave.

Comment: Why do you have it like this in /etc/hosts? 192.168.2.154 nodemaster.hbasecluster.com node-master. Is your host ame node-master? If so try just IP and host name

Comment: I think your quorum journal properties are not setup correctly

Comment: @VS_FF the hostname to my machine is nodemaster.hbasecluster.com. When I tried only node-master as the hostname it gave me and error of reverse lookup.

Comment: @Abhinav Can you please tell me how to set these properties? I have left all the quorum properties to be the default properties and my Zookeeper is set to be managed by HBase.

Comment: @Abhinav Can you please tell me how to set these properties? I have left all the quorum properties to be the default properties and my Zookeeper is set to be managed by HBase.

Comment: Here you go, all the properties you need if you're using QJM: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithNFS.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are using `bin/hbase-daemon.sh start master` to start the master, if yes, there should be more logs telling you about the actual problem with ERROR/FATAL just before the master is shutting down, and also you should see a similar line `"master.HMaster: STARTING service HMaster"` line in the logs when master starting up.

Below log line in regionserver says that either the regionserver port(16020) is utilized by another regionserver or application. Probably you have seen this while starting the regionserver again.

```
Caused by: org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: bind(..) failed: Address already in use
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.unix.Errors.newIOException(Errors.java:117)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.unix.Socket.bind(Socket.java:285)
    at org.apache.hbase.thirdparty.io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollChannel.doBind(AbstractEpollChannel.java:714)
```

Comment: I ran the command you mentioned and I have added the logs in the edit. Please help me figure out how to get this up. Also what is the difference between bin/start-hbase.sh and bin/hbase-daemon.sh start master?

Comment: I was able to correct the issue on regionserver port 16020.

Comment: I am using hadoop version 2.8.3 and hbase 2.1.0. Is there any compatibility issue that can cause this error?

Comment: "ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.SamplerBuilder" , seems like due to conflicting HTrace jar, probably Hadoop needs htrace-3.x version but it's not available, check your Hadoop lib or HBase lib, update the htrace version in hadoop-classpath to 3.2.0 or 4.1.0.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: I had this error "ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.htrace.SamplerBuilder" while starting master Hbase daemon (_hbase-2.1_) on Ubuntu 18.04 with Hadoop 3.1. As @AnkitSinghal said it is problem with finding htrace-core-3.1.0 inside HADOOP_HOME. I've copy htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar into $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib and this problem has gone.

Comment: Worked for me ..:)